# ¿Hay problemas en modo sandbox?

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy trabajando en modo SandBox

No se si algo pasa con MercadoPago o soy yo, pero no aparecen los iconos de algunos medios de pago. Estos iconos van variando. A veces aparecen bien todos y a veces no aparece ninguno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ademas cuando pago con tarjeta de crédito, me aparece la siguiente URL en Networks del Google Chrome:

https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payment_methods/track_error?public_key=TEST-891f3481-g311-jkgb-gh33-3a88332ea630&js_version=1.5.4&referer=https%3A//misitio.com.ar

¿Esta funcionando bien el modo Sandbox?

Comment: Hola, yo también estoy teniendo problemas, en mi caso es un error de:  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/card_tokens?public_key=TEST-f3b*********************e49c&js_version=1.5.4&referer=file%3A//. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema desde ayer: Failed to load https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/card_tokens?public_key=TEST-0000000000000000000: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://sandbox.mercadopago.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Algo que se me ocurre que puede deberse el problema es porque mi cuenta la homologue y esta en modo producción. Es raro que no pueda usar de todas formas el modo sandbox. Pero desde que la pase a producción que me empezo a dar ese error.

Si uds tambien la pasaron a producción, la unica forma seria crear otra cuenta para TEST y tenerla para modo sandbox

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no somos el servicio técnico de MercadoPago

Comment: Pablo Lozano, a pesar de que no sean el servicio técnico de MercadoPago,  es el foro de comunidad que ofrece MercadoPago para los developers en su web oficial (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago). A nosotros nos ayuda para solucionar los problemas ya que MercadoPago no ofrece una linea directa para atención técnica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, tuve el mismo problema y note que el endpoint v1/payment_methods entra y sale de funcionamiento constantemente cuando utilizas las credenciales de prueba.

Fijate que utilizando las credenciales de producción para traer los payment_methods no vas a tener problemas (Si tu app no esta homologada no importa, para los payment_methods podes usar las credenciales de producción).

Para los que están teniendo el problema de No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', también me volví loco con esto. El API de MercadoPago, aunque dice que y debería, no envía el header de Access Control, por lo que Chrome (Y otros exploradores) bloquean la conexión.

Pueden descargar la extensión Access-Control-Allow-Origin desde la tienda de Chrome para probar la integración o utilizar https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ como proxy para sus requests.

Escencialmente si quieren hacer un request a api.mercadopago.com hacen la request a "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.mercadopago.com". Si visitan el link del proxy encuentran las instrucciones para hostear su propio proxy, lo cual les recomiendo por motivos de seguridad y estabilidad de sus plataformas.

Espero haberlos ayudado!

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Franco, gracias por tu respuesta! Yo hice una prueba unos dias mas tarde y funco sin modificar nada. Quizas el problema estaba en el servicio de mercadopago y no estaba funcionando corresctamente para el modo sandbox